# Клавиатура заслоняет поле для ввода

Tags: android, java

Собственно проблема описана в заголовке. В манифесте в активити, в котором производится набор текста, добавил 
    `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, но проблема осталась.

Может, кто знает, как решить?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```